# firemonkey set mouse cursor position

Tags: position, cursor, mouse, firemonkey

I wonder if there is a way to set the mouse cursor position in a FireMonkey app for Windows. It must be done on a MouseMove event. I've already tried ClipCursor and SetCursorPos. Thanks.

Comment: Does SetCursorPos work if it's NOT in aMouseMove event?

Comment: SetCursorPos works fine for me. Please show some code and let us know what happens when you use that code.

Comment: @Sebastian Z.I'll add some code, but, in the meantime, please tell me: did you ever used SetCursorPos in a MouseMove event?

Comment: Yes, I tested that and it works fine.

Comment: @Sebastian Z. I appologize for my mistake. Turns out that I should convert the X, Y coordinates to screen coordinates. Doing so, it works. I take your comment as the right answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetCursorPos(X, Y)` works fine inside a mouse move event. X and Y must be specified in screen coordinates.